# DevExpress Collectionview CollapseAllGroups doesn't collapse groups in Xamarin Forms App

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, uicollectionview, devexpress

I'm developing a xamarin forms app. I'm a new developer. I try to learn at the same time.

I use devexpress collectionview in Rg.Plugins.Popup page. When I open that popup it comes with all groups collapsed but next time groups are expanded always. I want always groups collapsed user click and expand any group like in the picture.

What do you need for giving advice ? I leave some information above.

[image]

Xaml:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {

        if(dxCollection.ItemCount >= 0) 
        {

            dxCollection.CollapseAllGroups();
        }
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
 public MenuPagePopUpViewModel()
    {
        GotoOtherPageCommand = new Command<FlyoutItemPage>(goOtherPage);
        OnLongPressCommand = new Command(onLongPress);
        fillAdvancedMenuList();
    }

async void fillAdvancedMenuList()
    {


        try
        {

           
            var menuList = await serviceManager.getMenuList();


            for (int i = 0; i < menuList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (menuList[i].GRUP == "A")
                {
                    FlyoutItemPage fPage = new FlyoutItemPage(menuList[i].GRUP);
                    MenuPageList.Add(fPage);
                }
               
            }


           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UserDialogs.Instance.Alert(new AlertConfig
            {
                Message = $"{ex.Message}",

                OkText = "Tamam"

            });
            throw;
        }



    }
```